# Can I choose what part of the HMTL returned of the src of an iFrame to be shown?

Tags: html, iframe

Can I select somehow what part of the reposne from the  src of iFrame to beshown in it? 
My situation: I have an iFrame and the resposne give me a compleate page with  3 invested tables. The ifromation that I want to show is at the innermost one and it is changing real time .
I am making aspx page.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the code you have used so far

Comment: You can try the window.scrollTo(x,y) JS function, if you know exactly what section the page needs to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

Add an anchor near the table you want to jump to and then add the name to your `src` in the `iframe`.

In the page you're loading:

```
<a name="table3"></a>
<table>
    ...
</table>
```

Your main page:

```
<iframe src="tables.html#table3"></iframe>
```